# Not being able to use Basic Auth in NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I'm using [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) and I want to use Basic Authentication, but I'm getting a 403 Error in the browser.
I created a secret with `data.auth` base64 obtained from a file created with `htpasswd` and in the Ingress, I've added the annotations

```
annotations:
  nginx.org/basic-auth-secret: htpasswd
  nginx.org/basic-auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
```

where `htpasswd` is the name of the secret in the same namespace as the ingress.

Checking the logs of the Nginx-ingress pod, I can find this

```
[error] 1783#1783: *68296 open() "/etc/nginx/secrets/my-demo-htpasswd" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What should I do to get the secrets loaded in the Ingress Controller?

Comment: Well, where is that `my-demo-htpasswd` name coming from?

Comment: that is the ingress name

Comment: And you have [given the `Secret` the correct `type:`](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v3.1.0/examples/ingress-resources/basic-auth/cafe-passwd.yaml#L5)? Have you already checked on the controller's filesystem to see if it mounted the file in some other place? We're not at your computer so this back and forth is not productive; what steps have you already tried in order to troubleshoot this for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

with "nginx.org" you need to use the secret type: nginx.org/htpasswd

```
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Secret  
metadata:  
  name: basic-auth  
type: nginx.org/htpasswd  
stringData:  
  htpasswd: <copy the contents of the htpasswd file here>

  example 
  htpasswd: foo:$apr1$T6zUs/pB$xvCvBUfMvvIk8r12lZz9C0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this instruction[1] to add basic authentication to kubernetes inginx controller.

[1]https://blog.petehouston.com/add-basic-authentication-to-kubernetes-ingress-nginx/

Comment: The instructions you point to are for the _community_ version of the Nginx-ingress controller (because the annotations start with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io`), however the original post includes annotations of the type `nginx.org/basic-auth-realm`, which are from the Nginx-company controller.